# inline server side script in asp control

Tags: javascript, asp.net, controls, inline, server-side

I want to call method of a particular class to assign a text to asp.net control. Throwing error called server tag not well formed. Note: no server side code

```
<asp:button id="btn" runat="server" text="<%#class1.getText("btn")%>"/>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

when you're doing inline code like this, you have to use single quotes to distinguish the start and end of the `text` value.

```
<asp:button id="btn" runat="server" text='<%#class1.getText("btn")%>'/>
```